# Adding more coefficients in R regression to exponential equation Y=a+b*(1-exp(-y/c))

Tags: r, regression, exponential, coefficients

i am running into a problem with R where I can not get enough coefficients to solve the exponential equation

Y=a+b*(1-exp(-X/c))

with X and Y being data variables and a,b,c fitting coefficients of the exponential equation. My current formula in R is:

```
 results = lm(Y~I(1-(exp(-X))),data=Data)
```

This gives:

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             0.2815     0.0689   4.086 0.002734 ** 
I(1 - (exp(I(-Y^2))))   0.9592     0.1894   5.065 0.000677 ***
```

I am pretty new to R, but could not find any answers in the manuals on how to implement the c coefficient. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: have a look at `nlme::nls`

Comment: Study the equation in `help("SSasymp")`. It's a reparameterization of your model. Then fit `nls(Y ~ SSasymp(X, Asym, R0, lrc), data = Data)`.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. I tried the nls function and installed the nlme package, but i seem to still be failing in characterizing the c variable. Don't know what exactly i'm doing wrong, but i found a solution through matlab in the mean time. 

You can use the cftool and use a two-term exponential model (a*exp(bx)+c*exp(dx)) with the d-term set to and bounded to 0 in the fit options. This effectively creates the formula a+b*exp(cx), which is another way to write the desired exponential equation. Caution should be used when reading the coefficients though.